# How to load URL image in PhotoView

Tags: android, android-layout, github

I'm trying to use PhotoView library of Chris Banes with enclosing sample. I made some changes in sample to load image from URL (on internet), not from drawable as sample . Here's the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
    mCurrMatrixTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_current_matrix);


    //here's the method to load URL image from URL
    new LoadImage().execute();
    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);

}

private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Simulates a background job.

        try {
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(grabImageFromUrl(image_url));               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace().toString();
        }                   
        return null;
    }

}

private Drawable grabImageFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
        return Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent(), "src");
        }
```

The problem was the image is not loaded then, just return a blank page. And the weird thing happened when I tried some pinch-zoom actions, the image was loaded, and worked normally. Anyone has suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the image into a bitmap first and then set the bitmap to the imageview.

Url to bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) { try { URL url = new URL(src); HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); connection.setDoInput(true); connection.connect(); InputStream input = connection.getInputStream(); Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input); return myBitmap; } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); return null; } }
```

and then use iv.setimagebitmap()

Comment: Hi, thank you for yr suggestion. However, it's just a switch from setimageDrawable to setimagebitmap. The problem is still there. Or I dont understand yr point clearly, if so please explain me more. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
    private Bitmap bmp;
bmp = new Bitmap[1];

// to fetch the image
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, screenWidth, screenHeight);
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url, new Rect(), options);


// to set the image
 Runnable action = new Runnable() {
   public void run() { bmp = bitmap
     }
  };
 runOnUiThread(action);
```

Now you have the image in bmp. Take it and set in the Adapter for your Gallery.

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(container.getContext());
PhotoViewAttacher attacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
attacher.update();
```